# Checking columns with case statement

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case

I have a table with the following column, in SQL Server 2012:

```
ID YEARNBR
-----------
1   2016
2   2015
3   2014
4   2013
1   2015
1   2014
2   2016
```

I wanted to create a case statement that would check this column `YEARNBR`:

```
(case 
    when yearNBR = 2017 and YearNBR = 2016 and YearNBR = 2015 and yearNBR = 2014 
       then 1 
       else 0 
 end)
```

If my column `YEARNBR` would contain the year 2016, 2015, and 2014 and I would be grouping by ID, then I would want another column that would be called: `2014Through2016` that would contain the value 1.

```
ID  2014Through2016    2015Through2016  2016
--------------------------------------------
1    1                      1             1
2    0                      1             1
3    0                      0             0
4    0                      0             0
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Search for PIVOT function

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when yearnbr in (2014, 2015, 2016) then 1 else 0 end) as yr_2014_2016,
       max(case when yearnbr = 2016 then 1 else 0 end) as yr_2015
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

**create a sameple table:**

```
CREATE TABLE yearz(
  id int,
  yearnbr int
)

INSERT INTO yearz (id,yearnbr)
VALUES 
(1,2016),
(2,2015),
(3,2014),
(4,2013),
(1,2015),
(1,2014),
(2,2016)
```

**using pivot to get your result:**

```
select id, [2014] as '2014through2016', [2015] as '2015through2016', [2016]
from 
(
  select id, yearnbr
  from yearz
) src
pivot
(
  count(yearnbr)
  for yearnbr in ([2014], [2015], [2016])
) piv;
```

**result:**

```
id          2014through2016 2015through2016 2016
----------- --------------- --------------- -----------
1           1               1               1
2           0               1               1
3           1               0               0
4           0               0               0
```

**Suggestion**
You should learn how to [use *PIVOT* and *UNPIVOT*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) they are pretty useful. and welcome to StackOverflow. If you find this or any other answer useful please mark it as the solution. That way it would help the community and fellow programmers who run into the same problem as you in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, sum(yr_2014_2016) as yr_2014_2016, sum(yr_2015_2016) as yr_2015_2016, sum(yr_2016) as yr_2016
from 
(
select id
, (case when yearnbr in (2014, 2015, 2016) then 1 else 0 end) as yr_2014_2016
, (case when yearnbr in (2015, 2016) then 1 else 0 end) as yr_2015_2016
, (case when yearnbr = 2016 then 1 else 0 end) as yr_2016
from t;
)
y
group by Id
```

Comment: In case you have more than one record of the exact same data.